# Como definir el ancho de una imagen sin aplicarle pixeles

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3

Quisiera saber definir el ancho de una imagen en un `div` sin tener la necesidad de aplicarle los pixeles, sino por porcentaje, ya que al aplicarle los píxeles al momento de aumentarle/bajarle la resolución quedaría con la misma longitud.

tengo el siguiente código, contiene bootstrap y lo que quiero es hacer que la imagen del fondo del paisaje este al 100% del contenedor pero al colocarle en el css de la imagen la propiedad `width=100%;` no lo toma.

```css
*{
 padding: 0px;
 margin:0px;
}
.container{

 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
#persona{
 z-index: 3
}
#contenido{
 z-index: 1;
}
#paisaje{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 310px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6" id="persona">
    <img src="http://www.medicinahiperbarica.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/persona-png.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-6 bg-warning" id="contenido">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi voluptatibus commodi fugit quod, animi alias architecto sapiente in aperiam facilis?</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12" id="paisaje">
    <img src="https://softwarelibreenmivida.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/cielo-recortado.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aquí tienes](http://jsfiddle.net/semagarcia/aq9Laaew/47598/) un jsfiddle para ver el resultado (la opción de Armando a mí no me ha funcionado).

Básicamente es organizar correctamente el contenido en rows y cols como recomienda bootstrap, y luego aplicar la regla del width / min-width de un 100%.

Comment: Funciono, pero podrias explicar que fue lo que hiciste que no estaba en mi codigo para que funcionase, por favor

Comment: Sí, por supuesto. Lo que he hecho ha sido primero organizar el código en base al grid de bootstrap, es decir _rows_ y _cols_. Así, la row por no estar dentro de ninguna otra, va a ocupar el 100% de la anchura. Luego he definido una sola columna, de 12, para que ocupe todo el ancho y se ajuste al padre (row). Por último, la imagen está colocada dentro de la columna (que ocupa todo el ancho), así que lo único que falta es aplicar una regla de CSS de 100% de ancho para que ocupe todo lo que ocupa su padre (todo el ancho). Hay una clase _no-padding_ para eliminar un pequeño espaciado de bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

En Bootsrap 4

```
<img src="cielo-recortado.jpg" class="img-fluid">
```

En Bootsrap 3

```
<img src="cielo-recortado.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: También puedes agregar en css lo siguiente: #paisaje img {
width:100% !important;
}

Comment: Utilice en img-fluid y no me funciono e intente agregandole el width a la imagen y tampoco me funciono.